# Access Xcom in S3ToSnowflakeOperatorof Airflow

Tags: jinja2, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My use case is i have an S3 event which triggers a lambda (upon an S3 createobject event), which in turn invokes an Airflow DAG passing in a couple of --conf values (bucketname, filekey).

I am then extracting the key value using a Python operator and storing in an xcom variable.  I then want to extract this xcom value within a S3ToSnowflakeOperator and essentially load the file into a Snowflake table.

All parts of the process are working bar the extraction of xcom value within the S3ToSnowflakeOperator task.  I basically get the following in my logs.

query: [COPY INTO "raw".SOURCE_PARAMS_JSON FROM @MYSTAGE_PARAMS_DEMO/ files=('{{ ti.xcom...]

which looks like the jinja template is not correctly resolving the xcom value.

My code is as follows:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils import timezone

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.transfers.s3_to_snowflake import S3ToSnowflakeOperator


FILEPATH = "demo/tues-29-03-2022-6.json"


args = {
    'start_date': timezone.utcnow(),
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag_conf',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['params demo'],
) as dag:

    
    def run_this_func(**kwargs):
        outkey = '{}'.format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['key'])
        print(outkey)
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        ti.xcom_push(key='FILE_PATH', value=outkey)


    run_this = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run_this',
        python_callable=run_this_func
    )

    get_param_val = BashOperator(
        task_id='get_param_val',
        bash_command='echo "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="FILE_PATH") }}"',
        dag=dag)


    copy_into_table = S3ToSnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='copy_into_table',
        s3_keys=["{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='FILE_PATH') }}"],
        snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
        stage=SNOWFLAKE_STAGE,
        schema="""\"{0}\"""".format(SNOWFLAKE_RAW_SCHEMA),
        table=SNOWFLAKE_RAW_TABLE,
        file_format="(type = 'JSON')",
        dag=dag,
    )

    run_this >> get_param_val >> copy_into_table
```

If I replace

s3_keys=["{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='FILE_PATH') }}"],

with

s3_keys=[FILEPATH]

My operator works fine and the data is loaded into Snowflake.  So the error is centered on resolving s3_keys=["{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='FILE_PATH') }}"],  i believe?

Any guidance/help would be appreciated.  I am using Airflow 2.2.2

Comment: What version of the Snowflake provider do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using AWS Managed Airflow, and have specified the following in my requirements.txt.  

snowflake-connector-python==2.4.5
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==1.3.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
apache-airflow-providers-amazon==1.4.0

Comment: Updated the following lib:  apache-airflow-providers-snowflake-2.6.0  however still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I removed the S3ToSnowflakeOperator and replaced with the SnowflakeOperator.

I was then able to reference the xcom value (as above) for the sql param value.

**my xcom value was a derived COPY INTO statement effectively replicating the functionality of the S3ToSnowflakeOperator. With the added advantage of being able to store the metadata file information within the table columns too.